# Searching an unsorted vector (c++)

Tags: search

What is the fastest method for searching an unsorted vector? 
Does it take longer to just search the vector from start to end or use std::sort then use a binary search algorithm?

Comment: In theory, sorting need O(n log n) and a binary search need O(log n). A sequential search need only O(n). So if you only need to search it once, sequential search is fine. If you need large number of searches on the same vector, the amortized cost may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if a vector is sorted then the fastest method would be to use std::is_sorted(). It's linear time.

If you need to sort it, you std::sort() which is the most efficient. O(n * log n)

So, checking is faster then sorting itself.